# onClickListener in onActivityResult doesn't working

Tags: android, android-intent, onclicklistener, onactivityresult

I have two activities, in first I have button Add, and by click on this button I send intent to second activity. In second activity, I have two EditText views and Save button, after pressing save I return to first activity and create in onActivityResult function TextView and two buttons - edit and go. When I press these buttons, nothing happens.

This is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == AddingRecipe)
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            LinearLayout ll2 = new LinearLayout(this);
            ll2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setId(id);
            tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            String disease = data.getStringExtra(AddEditRecipesActivity.Disease);
            String doctor = data.getStringExtra(AddEditRecipesActivity.Doctor);             
            tv.setText(disease +"\nВрач: "+ doctor);
            ll2.addView(tv);
            ImageButton edit = new ImageButton(this);
            edit.setId(id);
            edit.setClickable(true);
            edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)LayoutInflater.from(RecipesActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.activity_recipes, null);
                    for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
                        View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
                        if(child.getClass() == TextView.class && child.getId() == v.getId())
                        {
                        TextView tv2 = (TextView)child;
                        Intent i3 = new Intent(RecipesActivity.this, AddEditRecipesActivity.class);
                        i3.addFlags(EditingRecipe);
                        i3.putExtra(EditRecipe, tv2.getText().toString());
                        startActivityForResult(i3, EditingRecipe);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            edit.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edit);
            ll2.addView(edit);
            id = id + 1;
            ImageButton go = new ImageButton(this);
            go.setId(id);
            go.setClickable(true);
            go.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.go);
            go.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)LayoutInflater.from(RecipesActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.activity_recipes, null);
                    for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
                        View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
                        if(child.getClass() == TextView.class && child.getId() == v.getId())
                        {
                        TextView tv2 = (TextView)child;
                        Intent i3 = new Intent(RecipesActivity.this, MedicineActivity.class);
                        i3.putExtra(ShowRecipe, tv2.getId());
                        RecipesActivity.this.startActivity(i3);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            id = id + 1;
            ll2.addView(go);
            ll.addView(ll2);
        }
    }
}
```

What is my mistake? When I put onClickListener from function to onClick, my application crashes.

Thanks.

Updated: Debugger stepped into OnClick function. Maybe a problem in a loop in OnClick function. I identify my TextView and edit button with a same Id, and in a loop, I searching my TextView in all views of Activity with button id. And then it go to second activity again for edit data in TextView. But I can't understand, what's wrong with it.

Comment: I would recommend doing a check to see if `requestCode == AddingRecipe` actually even matches. If clicking on those buttons does nothing then one can only assume that it never sets the listener because it never steps into that block. Debug it or add a Log.

Comment: I checked, and it matched. Moreover, it stepped into OnClick function. Maybe a problem in a loop in OnClick function.

I identify my TextView and edit button with a same Id, and in a loop, I searching my TextView in all views of Activity with button id. And then it go to second activity again for edit data in TextView. But I can't understand, what's wrong with it.